# Take a Ten Minute Walk (Codewars) - Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing, range

I am doing a Python exercise on Codewars. These are the instructions:

"You live in the city of Cartesia where all roads are laid out in a perfect grid. You arrived ten minutes too early to an appointment, so you decided to take the opportunity to go for a short walk. The city provides its citizens with a Walk Generating App on their phones -- everytime you press the button it sends you an array of one-letter strings representing directions to walk (eg. ['n', 's', 'w', 'e']). You always walk only a single block for each letter (direction) and you know it takes you one minute to traverse one city block, so create a function that will return true if the walk the app gives you will take you exactly ten minutes (you don't want to be early or late!) and will, of course, return you to your starting point. Return false otherwise.

Note: you will always receive a valid array containing a random assortment of direction letters ('n', 's', 'e', or 'w' only). It will never give you an empty array (that's not a walk, that's standing still!)."

This is the code I wrote:

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
    #determine if walk is valid
    location = 0
    if len(walk) == 10:
        for i in range(0, len(walk)):
            if walk[i+1] == walk[i] or walk[i-1] == walk[i]:
                return False
            else:
                if i == 'n':
                    location+=1
                elif i == 's':
                    location-=1
                elif i == 'w':
                    location+=2
                elif i == 'e':
                    location-=2
        return location == 0
    else:
        return False
```

I seem to have an indexing error. It says it is out of range.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    test.expect(is_valid_walk(['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']), 'should return True');
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 7, in is_valid_walk
    if walk[i+1] == walk[i] or walk[i-1] == walk[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone please point out how can I fix this?

Comment: When `i` is the length of `walk`what does `walk[i+1]` refer to? eg - your last `i` will be equal to 9 which is the 10th item of `walk`, but then you're asking for `walk[10]` which is not going to work.

Comment: I see what you mean. How would I index it here then in this case?

Comment: I don't know - that's logic you'll have to work out... I'm not sure what that `if` is even trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in the following part of code.

```
if len(walk) == 10:
        for i in range(0, len(walk)):
            if walk[i+1] == walk[i] or walk[i-1] == walk[i]: #IndexError here
                return False
```

IndexError occurs when you're trying to get an index that does not exist in the list or is out of bounds for that list. Here loop will run from 0 to 9, which means your code will try to compare `walk[9+1]` i.e. `walk[10]` in the last iteration. Since, indexes 0 to 9 are defined for list walk it will give an index error when we try for index 10 or `i=10`. Similarly check for `walk[i-1]` when `i=0`.

This can be resolved by adding appropriate if conditions for the same.